# why start intent in new Thread does not work on real device

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application with one activity.
I want it to be always on, so when it stops, after 30 seconds the application opens again.
here is my code:

in onCreate function:

```
p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    p.edit().putBoolean("isRunning",true).commit();
```

in onResume function:

```
p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    p.edit().putBoolean("isRunning",true).commit();
```

in onStop function:

```
final MainActivity mainActivity = this;
p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        p.edit().putBoolean("isRunning",false).commit();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (!p.getBoolean("isRunning", false)) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "starting intent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mainActivity, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }).run();
```

on my emulator that code works perfectly, but when I run it on real device, I get toast "starting intent" but actually it remains in the other activity.

I have appLock application installed on my device - is it connected?

## UPDATE

**I want it to be clear: there is no problem in logic, because in the emulator works.**

**my problem is that on real device it does not work.**

**I get the toast but startintent does not occur.**

Comment: I would use an AsyncTask, Timer, or Handler for this instead of a Thread...

Comment: I have tried Timer and Handler before, no results.

Comment: For the AsyncTask, just do Thread.sleep in the doInBackground, then return, and put the toast and intent in onPostExecute

Comment: I am trying it, thanks.

Comment: I tried it, no change.

Comment: Aren't you currently in MainActivity? Your intent is trying to start MainActivity, so I don't think anything should be happening

Comment: no, thread is starting in onStop function, so after the delay it is not in MainActivity. in additional if the user came back to MainActivity, the variable "isRunning" in sharedpreferences is set to true, so I dont have to see toast.

Comment: So you're trying to prevent MainActivity from stopping?

Comment: Why aren't you starting activity in main thread?? I mean runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "starting intent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  Intent intent = new Intent(mainActivity, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });

Comment: Please ignore if I am wrong but because I cant format the code in comment am putting it in answers

Comment: Can you please check if my updated answer serves your need :)

Comment: I am checking, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simple yet working solution. I tested it on device and is working absolutely fine.

What I did. Create a Application Activity, in the on stop of your activity ask Application activity to restart it after the delay :)

Here is my working code :)

```
package com.example.sandeepbhandari.myapplication;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Created by sandeepbhandari on 3/3/16.
 */
public class AppService extends Application{
    private static AppService sInstance;
    public static boolean isUserActivityRunning=false;

    private static final ScheduledExecutorService worker = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    public void startUserActivity(){
        if(!isUserActivityRunning) {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(!PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppService.this).getBoolean("isRunning",false))
                    {
                        Intent userActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        userActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        getApplicationContext().startActivity(userActivity);
                    }
                }
            }, 30000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("isRunning",true).commit();
        sInstance = this;
    }

    public static AppService getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

In order to use it update your manifest file as below

```
<application
        android:name=".AppService" //your application activity name
```

In your activity onStop and onStart simply call

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    AppService service = AppService.getInstance();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("isRunning",true).commit();
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    AppService service = AppService.getInstance();   
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("isRunning",false).commit();
    service.startUserActivity();
    finish();
}
```

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: as I said, my problem is that in real device it does not work. in emulator it works perfectly!!!

Comment: I dont see where you check if my application is running. if it is running I dont want it to reopen.

Comment: You dont have to sir :) You call Application Activty's startUserActivity(method which will restart your activity) only in onStop of your activity which needs to be re-started. So If its running onStop will not get called hence nobody will call the startUserActivity, so no issue :)

Comment: I wanted to handle situation when the user came back to application before 30 seconds after stopping.

Comment: If thats your concern, gimme 2 min lemme update my code again :)

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. Thanks.

Comment: If you can see I have added a static boolean variable in Application  isUserActivityRunning which gets set to true in onStart of your activity and set to false in onStop :) So you will restart the activity in startUserActivity only when it is false :) in other words when its not running :)

Comment: it works, but MainActivity is open also when the user came beck before :(

Comment: Sorry!! I didnt get that, Yeah mainActivity is open because it started user activity, user activity gets reloaded after the delay u specified in application class :) Whats the issue??

Comment: I update your answer, saved variable in shared preferences in place of the static variable, and now it works every case. I was completely discouraged and still dont believe it works. Huge thanks!!!

Comment: Awesome :) Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Handler` in MainActivity.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message m){
        Intent intent = new Intent(mainActivity, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "starting intent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

Then send a message to the handler inside the thread as follows,

```
handler.sendMessage(1);
```

So your code will become,

```
if (!p.getBoolean("isRunning", false)) {
    hander.sendMessage(1);
}
```

Comment: your solution is wonderfull, but as I said, my problem is that in real device it does not work. in emulator it works perfectly!!!

Comment: @Ariela Is there any error on debugging on the real device?

Comment: how can I see it? i tried to surround all code with try and catch and show toast when there is an exception, but there is no exception.

Comment: @Ariela Connect your device with USB debugging turned on and click debug in the IDE.

Comment: @Ariela So that means there are no exceptions.

Comment: @Ariela What is the value of `p.getBoolean("isRunning", false)`?

Comment: it is false, I'm sure it is false because I see the toast of "starting intent", but the activity is not starting.

Answer (score 0):

Use Handler to start activity for safe inside thread:

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler(){
 public void handleMessage(Message m){
      Intent intent = new Intent(mainActivity, MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
  }
};
```

Inside thread call to myHandler bellow:

```
final MainActivity mainActivity = this;
p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        p.edit().putBoolean("isRunning",false).commit();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (!p.getBoolean("isRunning", false)) {

                      myHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 3000);  //delay 3000ms and send message to handler to start intent                  

                }
            }
 }).run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to start the same activity when it's `OnStop` is called. It's illegal to try to do that as you are tying to prevent the Activity from ever being stopped

Comment: as I said, my problem is that in real device it does not work. in emulator it works perfectly!!!